# Ошибка при запуске vagrant

Tags: vagrant, homestead

При попытке запустить vagrant, `vagrant up` возникает ошибка:

> The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
>   assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
>   should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
>   went wrong.

Как ее решить?

Comment: Ну как минимум сделать то, что написано. Т.е. прочитать логи и найти вывод команды. По этому выводу уже и задавать вопросы, если он сам не подскажет что не так

Comment: Прошу прощение за глупый вопрос, но как их посмотреть?

Comment: `The output for this command should be in the log above` - что означает "вывод этой команды должен быть приведен выше". Т.е. там же, где эту ошибку нашли, там выше и смотрите.